# Python Flask: urls to different websites as variables

Tags: python, flask

Hi I'm currently learning Flask and was wondering how I can put a link to another website as a variable? I have included the code below, basically I would like to link things like facebook, li etc as a variable.

```
@app.route('/social')
def social():
    return render_template('index.html', 
        **mainbody = ("Links to social things are here, facebook, linkedin etc email https://www.facebook.com/")**,
        number = number,
        bettotal = bettotal,
        winnings = "%0.2f" % winnings, 
        result = ("Place a bet!"))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why not make a dictionary of linkes and names and render them in jinja2?

Comment: I'll have a look at this, thank you!